# Monitoring the filesystem with Haskell

Tags: haskell, filesystems

I'm using the [FSNotify](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fsnotify-0.0.6) package to watch my filesystem for changes to markdown files, so I can run them through [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) automatically. However, I'm having trouble getting the manager to exit nicely.

As it stands, my code is based on [Yesod's use of the same package](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/yesod-bin/Devel.hs#L167):

```hs
module Main where

import System.FSNotify
import Filesystem (getWorkingDirectory)
import System.Exit
import Control.Concurrent

main = do
    cwd <- getWorkingDirectory
    putStrLn "Watching current directory, press RETURN to exit."
    withManager $ \man -> do
        _ <- forkIO $ do
            watchTree man cwd (const True) $ \fp -> print fp
        _ <- getLine
        exitSuccess
```

When I use `runhaskell`, the program works perfectly, but if I compile it to an executable (using `ghc --make`), when I press enter, my terminal becomes unresponsive. I'm compiling this on Windows 7 64-bit.

EDIT: [Completed code](https://gist.github.com/eightyeight/5591481). Well, not entirely completed - there's still more I want to do with this - but working.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Whenever I see a question of the form "works in GHCi, hangs when compiled", I think to myself "you need the threaded runtime".

Try recompiling with `-threaded` and see if that helps.

(GHCi is compiled with this flag, which explains the difference. I do recall there's some difference in how external function calls work depending on whether you use the threaded runtime or not...)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm - once I realised GHC wasn't rebuilding my executable since I hadn't changed the source file, just the compiler flags :P.